# Create UDF function from phpmyadmin MySql

Tags: mysql, function, phpmyadmin, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create the `sys_eval` function using phpmyadmin using this query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sys_eval RETURNS string SONAME 'C:\\xampp\\mysql\\lib\\plugin\\lib_mysqludf_sys.dll';
```

But i'm getting the following error:

```
error 1124 (hy000) no paths allowed for shared library
```

Even when i have the `lib_mysqludf_sys.dll` in the plugin folder inside  Mysql folder:

[Plugin_dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvy8Z.png)

Comment: Are you doing this as the `root` user?

Comment: @tadman yes, I am.